# Mirroring with regex in wget

Tags: regex, wget

I'm using wget and trying to mirror all 98 folders on a website. What would be the syntax to do "wget -mk http://example.com/folder[1-98]/"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in $(seq 1 98);do echo "http://example.com/folder${i}/";done|wget -mki -
```

Answer (score 0):

`wget` does not support specifying URL ranges in the format you've described. You would be better served building out the range of links with bash or some other programming language into a text file and then reading that text file with wget.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply {} to apply range of numbers. Use this example "wget -mk http://example.com/folder{1..98}"